# No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’

Tags: haskell

```
data Tick = Tick
  { _price :: Int
  , _timestamp :: TimeOfDay
  } deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Num Tick where
  (-) (Tick a b) (Tick a' _) = Tick (a - a') b


calcAxis :: High -> Low -> Int
calcAxis (Just (Tick a _)) (Just (Tick b _)) = (fromIntegral (a - b)) / 2
```

I understand dividing `Int`'s will produce a `Float`, so I need to cast the `Int`'s using `fromIntegral` before using `(/)` however I still get error:

```
• No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
• In the expression: (fromIntegral (a - b)) / 2
  In an equation for ‘calcAxis’:
      calcAxis (Just (Tick a _)) (Just (Tick b _))
        = (fromIntegral (a - b)) / 2
```

I dont really understand what its asking me to do. Surely I don't have to define an instance for `Fractional Int`?

I assume I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error message is complaining about the entire expression `(fromIntegral (a - b)) / 2` — this is Fractional, but you've asked (via the type signature of `calcAxis`) for it to be `Int`.

Comment: If I remove the division and update the signature for `calcAxis` to return a `Float` it typechecks ok.

Comment: @Globalkeith: Why would you do both? Update the signature to return a `Float` and don’t remove the division.

Comment: Doh, ignore me - it typechecks when it returns a `Float`!! thanks

Comment: Yes, it's probably the right thing to just keep the result a fractional type. Though `Float` is pretty unusual in Haskell, normally the higher-precision `Double` or exact `Rational` are prefered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ryan commented, it's probably the right thing to just keep the result a fractional type. `Float` is pretty unusual in Haskell though, normally the higher-precision `Double` or exact `Rational` are prefered.

```
calcAxis :: High -> Low -> Double
calcAxis (Just (Tick a _)) (Just (Tick b _)) = fromIntegral (a - b) / 2
calcAxis _ _ = ... -- keep in mind to handle the `Nothing` case as well!
```

That said, if you have a reason to make the result `Int`, and always want to round towards zero, that can be done simply with *integer division*:

```
calcAxis :: High -> Low -> Int
calcAxis (Just (Tick a _)) (Just (Tick b _)) = (a - b) `quot` 2
```

...or, if you always want to round down,

```
calcAxis (Just (Tick a _)) (Just (Tick b _)) = (a - b) `div` 2
```

Comment: Thank you, for anyone at my level this response is rich in educational value. I appreciate it.

Comment: I hope I don't offend anyone by selecting this response but it goes above and beyond to help me, so that deserves recognition, and would be helpful for future users.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you end up with a float after using `/` and your type spec says you should be returning an Int.

You need to either round/truncate convert to Int or change the type signature of calcAxis.

```
> let a = 1 :: Int
> let b = 2 :: Int
> let c = (fromIntegral (a - b)) / 2
> :t c
c :: Fractional a => a
```

And there's no instance for `Fractional Int` is what the type error is indicating.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I do appreciate it. Yes I realised when @Shreevatsar asked about the signature.